# Create an Insert object

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I am learning SQL Alchemy. I have a list of column names from a CSV file. I want to create insert statements for each row (or a single insert for all rows). So far I have

```
with open('tablename.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader)

    for data in reader:
        query = insert(table(table_name), columns, data)
        print(str(query))
```

This just prints

```
INSERT INTO tablename () VALUES ()
```

for each row in the CSV file.

How do I correctly provide the column names and values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the compiled INSERT statement is empty is caused by 2 things: the [light weight table construct](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) you've used has no [columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) defined, and 
the first 3 arguments to [`insert()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert) are table, [values](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values), and inline – not table, columns and values. Reading related documentation is a good start when running in to trouble.

An SQLAlchemy insert construct can be used either by just [passing it to execute, accompanied with the desired values](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), or as a single `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement. Either way if not passing full table tuples you have to pass dictionaries of column, value pairs:

```
tbl = table(table_name, *(column(c) for c in columns))
values = [dict(zip(columns, data)) for data in reader]

# A single INSERT statement with multiple values
stmt = insert(tbl).values(values)
engine.execute(stmt)

# More traditional executemany
engine.execute(insert(tbl), values)
```

Comment: I am trying to digest large amounts of sqlalchemy docs today. So I can specify just the column names and can leave out their types?

Comment: Does `[dict(zip(columns, data)) for data in reader]` have to be a list or can it be a generator?

Comment: To your first question, when using the light weight `table()` and `column()` constructs the `type_` is not necessarily required, if you pass suitable values that your DB-API driver can handle in a manner that produces SQL convertible to the column's type and/or the type in question requires no special bind/SQL processing.

Comment: And to the second, not sure. The docs mainly [refer to list](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), or *args.